# Spring PersistanceContext,EntityManager and working with your database

Tags: java, database, spring, persistence

I have been working on some basic Spring web apps and have gotten in too some trouble with properly managing my database. I've been using basic JPA repositories since now and the classic save() and findById(long id) have been getting the job done for me. However recently i noticed that when i get a object from the database and change it, it does not get persisted. That lead me to googling about all the things in the title of the question. What i found has really confused me, so maybe someone can clear it up for me:

- I have noticed that some people use Session(from persistence) and
  some use the EntityManager. Why?
- Some people have said that you MUST inject a EntityManagerFactory, and get an EntityManager from there, is this true and why ?

  - I have not been able to properly do this, after following one or two guides, anyone else wanna give me an explanation on how to do it ?
  - i have seen that EntityManagerFactory get injected in a thousand diffrent ways (quite confusing), which would be the best?
- I have seen this `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);` 
  this gave me an entityManager to work with, but i had errors, and people about this said that: `With regards to the original question about obtaining an EntityManagerFactory in a non-spring setting. You simply call Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);`, what would this non-spring setting be?
- Is there a difference if im working on development in a simple H2 database, or on a mysql database ?

  - Link to a good and up to date tutorial or recommendation of a book that covers this, i study this in class, and they never mentioned anything about persistence context and entity managment, so im quite confused.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: *recently i noticed that when i get a object from the database and change it, it does not get persisted*: that will only happen if you do that from a transactional method. If you don't, then the entity you load becomed unmanaged (detached) as soon as the repository method returns.

Comment: All theese seem to be things i already know how to do. Im interested in the entityManager, and manipulating and persiting the entities to the database. or is there another chapter in your link i just cant find ?

Comment: If you really need to get an EntityManager inside a Spring application, just inject it using `@PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager`. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-jpa-dao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four ways to use spring DAO :

- JdbcTemplate + Spring DAO suppport (you will use JdbcTemplate class)
- Hibernate+ Spring DAO support (you will use SessionFactory class)
- JPA + spring DAO support (you will use the EntityManager class)
- JPA + Spring Data (High level abstraction for DAO)

JDBC, Hibernate, JPA, are independent technologies. If you will learn `hibernate`, you will learn how to use `SessionFactory`. Same for `jpa` and `EntityManager`. [Spring Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) is another abstraction from spring for accessing database.

For more information about the spring DAO support, please check the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#dao)

Comment: Im working with JPA repositories and Hibernate does the mapping to the database, so which tech am i using ?

Comment: If you are using JPA repositories interfaces, you are using spring Data. Then you don't need to use EntityManager or SessionFactory directly.

Comment: Then how would i fix this issue?
personRepository.save(someguy)
personRepository.findById("1").setName("BlaBla")
The other name does not get persisted.

I know i could do
Person temp=personRepository.findById("1");
temp.setName("BlaBla")
personRepository.save(temp);

But isn't saving twice bad? Also will i not get into more issues without knowledge of manipulating with the entities?

Comment: Have you called the method CrudRepository.save(person) to save it? This is the way to persist an entity if you are using spring data.

Comment: Yes, but then if in a method i want to change its name, after i get it and change its name, should i save again? is this not bad? Does it know its the same entity i took so i can change it?

Comment: Spring data will know as your entity is a managed entity. The save method persists or merges the given entity by using the JPA EntityManager.

Comment: Please read the documentation for spring data for more information.

Comment: You're welcome. If it was helpful, please mark as response. Thanks

Comment: I wanna leave it up for a an hour or two more, after that i will give you answer response :) thanks again!!